how gradient descent is calculated in NN if the layer is not having any weights
Consider the simple NN with three layers. second layer is my custom layer where i have not having any weights or bias, I just forwarded the input multiplied with some constant value. I understood the forward propagation flow, but I am not understanding how backpropagation is working with custom layer. i was expecting the gradient decent to zero since the derivative of a constant is zero but it calculated the gradient decent with some value, I am not sure how the gradient decent is calculated.
import torch as t
import torch.nn as nn

class customlayer(nn.Module):
 def __init__(self):
     super(customlayer, self).__init__()
 def forward(self, x):
     return x.mul(0.001)

def hookFunc(module, gradInput, gradOutput):
   print(module)
   print(gradInput)
   print(gradOutput)

random_input = t.randn(2,2)

random_output = t.randn(1,1)
print('Random input is ', random_input)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
# model
l1 = nn.Linear(2, 3, bias=False)
l2 = customlayer()
l3 = nn.Linear(3, 1, bias=False)


l1.register_backward_hook(hookFunc)
l2.register_backward_hook(hookFunc)
l3.register_backward_hook(hookFunc)

intermediate1 = l1(random_input)
intermediate2 = l2(intermediate1)
output= l3(intermediate2)

loss = criterion(output ,random_output)
loss.backward()

print(l1.weight)

print('--------------------------------------------')
print(l1.weight.grad)
print(l3.weight.grad)

print('-----------------------------------------------') ```


Gradient descent is not calculated for a single layer except the case where you only have one layer. In all other cases, descent is calculated for the entire sequence and with this structure is doesn't matter that your middle layer doesn't affect gradient in any way. You can test this by dropping layers 1 and 3 and should hopefully see 0 gradients for your custom layer.

What you print is the gradient of the input and output activation of a layer, not the gradient of the parameters, so if your grad_output of the custom layer is from the grad_input of the l3 layer, it will be some value.
